# How can I get a row echelon matrix?

Tags: matrices, ring-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a composite number and $s,t\in\mathbb{N}^*$.

Given $\mathbf{M}\in\mathbf{Z}_n^{s\times t}$, how can I get a row echelon form matrix?

What's more, how can we guarantee that the downmost non-zero row is unique？

Comment: Do you know how to get row echelon matrix in general?

Comment: Row Echelon Form means the triangle matrix gotten with Gaussian elimination?

Comment: I know how to get row echelon matrix in general. But  how can we guarantee that the downmost non-zero row is unique ?

Comment: I'm wondering if we can do Gaussian elimination on a non-unique decomposition ring,such as Zn[x],where n is not a prime.

Comment: You have to reduce all the elements of row reduced form, by modulus n, and if you take all elements in the range $[0,n)$, then of course , each row must be unique in the way , you reduced.

Comment: I 'm wondering if you could provide some references for your conclusions. I seem to have some doubts about the uniqueness of this question.